# Lubuntu not booting without USB used to install it

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb, lubuntu

My Lubuntu v12.04 (I'm not using the newest one because my Laptop doesn't support PAE) doesn't boot when the USB I used to install it isn't plugged in. I've overwritten my Windows XP with Lubuntu and the hard drive is the top priority in the boot options. I can even remove the USB while Lubuntu is running, it just needs it for booting, which is really annoying. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you installed the bootloader on the USB device, not the hard drive. If this is indeed the problem, when the system is booted up, `grub-install` should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Boot your Laptop with USB plugged.

Remove the USB while Lubuntu is running.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub-common grub2-common
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install  /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
update-grub
reboot
```

Boot your Laptop with USB unplugged.

Comment: I'll name my firstborn in your memory, that worked!